# legend overlaps the chart in highchart after restore down the browser

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working on a chart given below.

https://jsfiddle.net/2nn9q1oo/6/ (see code at bottom of question)

The margin is set for `legend` but it is not working when I click on `Restore down` on browser.

The issue being that the `legend` overlaps the chart.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    "chart": {
        "zoomType": "x",
        "spacingRight": "5",
        "spacingBottom": 0,
        "marginBottom": "50",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "renderTo": "container_0-0_CA3B1DE2-93BC-E451-B40E-EA0594CF6192"
    },
    "defs": {
        "patterns": [{
            "id": "0099CCpattern",
            "path": {
                "d": "M 0 0",
                "stroke": "#0099CC",
                "strokeWidth": 1
            }
        }]
    },
    "title": {
        "text": null
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": null
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "",
            "style": {
                "color": "#333",
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                "fontSize": "12px",
                "fontFamily": "Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif"
            }
        },
        "lineColor": "#909090",
        "categories": ["J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A", "S", "O", "N", "D", "Y"],
        "lineWidth": 1.3,
        "labels": {
            "staggerLines": 1,
            "enabled": true,
            "align": "center",
            "rotation": 0
        }
    },
    "yAxis": [{
        "className": "highcharts-axisv1",
        "plotLines": [{
            "value": 0,
            "color": "#909090",
            "width": 1
        }],
        "gridLineWidth": 0,
        "minorGridLineWidth": 0,
        "gridLineColor": "#EEEEEE",
        "lineColor": "#909090",
        "lineWidth": "0",
        "reversedStacks": false,
        "max": null,
        "title": {
            "text": "ACT (Mio. EUR)Mio. EUR",
            "style": {
                "color": "#333",
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                "fontSize": "12px",
                "fontFamily": "Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif"
            }
        },
        "labels": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    }, {
        "className": "highcharts-axisv2",
        "plotLines": [{
            "value": 0,
            "color": "#909090",
            "width": 1
        }],
        "gridLineWidth": 0,
        "minorGridLineWidth": 0,
        "gridLineColor": "#EEEEEE",
        "lineColor": "#909090",
        "lineWidth": "0",
        "reversedStacks": false,
        "title": {
            "text": "",
            "style": {
                "color": "#333",
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                "fontSize": "12px",
                "fontFamily": "Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif"
            }
        },
        "opposite": true,
        "labels": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    }],
    "legend": {
        "highlightSeries": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "layout": "horizontal",
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "bottom",
        "floating": false,
        "padding": 0,
        "margin": 120,
        "itemStyle": {
            "fontWeight": "normal"
        }
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "stacking": null,
            "grouping": true
        },
        "series": {
            "events": {},
            "point": {
                "events": {}
            },
            "dataLabels": {
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "9px"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {},
    "series": [{
        "type": "column",
        "name": "PYssss",
        "data": [598139000, 539771000, 625096000, 663746000, 591762000, 703818000, 781812000, 605727000, 617162000, 713368000, 669983000, 640068000],
        "stack": "0",
        "yAxis": 0,
        "color": "#66CCFF",
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "visible": true,
        "pointPadding": -0.3,
        "groupPadding": 0.25,
        "appendix": "Mio. EUR",
        "decimal": "1",
        "displayOrder": "0",
        "index": "0",
        "legendIndex": "0",
        "zIndex": "10"
    }, {
        "type": "column",
        "name": "CYwwwww vwwwww ww",
        "data": [596511000, 655649000, 786752000, 609689000, 853660000, 794944000, 749294000, 673385000, 793836000, 0, null, null],
        "stack": "0",
        "yAxis": 0,
        "color": "#0099CC",
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "visible": true,
        "pointPadding": -0.3,
        "groupPadding": 0.25,
        "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "color": "black",
            "inside": false,
            "crop": false,
            "overflow": "none",
            "style": {
                "fontWeight": "normal"
            }
        },
        "appendix": "Mio. EUR",
        "decimal": "1",
        "displayOrder": "1",
        "index": "1",
        "legendIndex": "1",
        "zIndex": "10"
    }, {
        "type": "column",
        "name": "BUDwwwwwwww",
        "data": [589905625.92, 578155929.93, 665928500.46, 640189735.54, 637354917.64, 672093454.04, 672548027.03, 627794143.76, 693162911.45, 688321249.35, 672359718.53, 692690283.6],
        "stack": "0",
        "yAxis": 0,
        "color": "white",
        "borderWidth": 1,
        "visible": true,
        "form": "budgetCols",
        "borderColor": "#0099CC",
        "pointPadding": -0.3,
        "groupPadding": 0.25,
        "appendix": "Mio. EUR",
        "decimal": "1",
        "displayOrder": "2",
        "index": "2",
        "legendIndex": "2",
        "zIndex": "10"
    }]
});
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: The code in your js fiddle is not working,please upload a working code in the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2nn9q1oo/6/   check  this one I think this will work.

Comment: When you resize the window and the chart is getting smaller, do the legend overlaps? I think you should just set min-height property on the div container.

Comment: Fixed the link and stated the question clearly

Comment: Added relevant code